# How to integrate an equation with multiple non-independent variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm a little lost with this particular equation, I have three variables which need to be integrated and can't quite wrap my mind to get the correct result.

I have this:

$$
\frac{dH}{dt}=8\pi V_{0}-3H^{2}(t)
$$
Can I solve this for H(t)?

Also, H can be written as: $H=\frac{da}{adt}$, where $a$ is a function of time giving me:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{da}{adt}\right)=8\pi V_{0}-3\left(\frac{da}{adt}\right)^{2}
$$

I'm just lost at this point, anyone that can keep a clear head and do this I'd be very appreciative if you can show me an applicable method...

Many thanks

Comment: This is an ODE of the "separable kind" : $$t=\int \frac{dH}{8\pi V_0-3H^2}$$ First integrate to obtain $t$ as a function of $H$; Then inverse this function to obtain $H(t)$

Comment: @JJacquelin Surely it's not, because H is a function of time? The $H^2$ you see is actually $H(t)^2$...

Comment: @ Michael Roberts : Surely it's yes. May be you don't know the separation of variables method to solve some EDOs ?http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationofVariables.html

Comment: @JJacquelin But $H$ is a function of time!!??

Comment: @JJacquelin So we have $\frac{dx}{dy}=x(y)$

Comment: Of coure $H$ is function of time,  since the goal is to find a solution of the ODE which is function of time. But the integral above a function of $H$ integrated relatively to $H$, You will have to learn this part of the differential calculus !

Comment: @JJacquelin I'm pretty certain you can not separate variables on this one. The end result is to find H(t) but in the original equation we have $H(t)$, I simply don't believe you on this one. If I'm wrong, I'm wrong. But I don't think you can separate variables on this.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy}=f(x)\quad\to\quad dy=\frac{dx}{f(x}\quad\to\quad y=\int \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ where $x=H$ and $y=t$

Comment: @JJacquelin Again, this is not $\frac{dx}{dy}=f(y)$, this is $\frac{dx}{dy}=x(y)$!! How many more times? In your separation of variables you have H, this should be H(t). Therefore you can not simply separate variables!!!

Comment: Well, we stop here the dialogue of the deaf, up you study the above link.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

The ODE is of separable kind :
$$dt=\frac{dH}{8\pi V_0-3H^2}$$
$$t=\int \frac{dH}{8\pi V_0-3H^2}= \frac{ 1 }{2\sqrt{6\pi V_0 }}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{\pi V_0}} H\right)+\text{constant}$$
This gives $t$ as a function of $H$. Inverse this function to find $H(t)$.

Note :

If you don't understand the integral, this could help you :

$\int \frac{dH}{8\pi V_0-3H^2}= \int \frac{\frac{dH(t)}{dt}}{8\pi V_0-3H(t)^2}dt \quad$ and apply the chain rule for integration.

Comment: As I keep saying, the H you have on the first line in the first integral should be H(t) not H

Comment: Hence, you can't separate it from dt

Comment: @ Michael Roberts: I hope that a smart teacher will finally make you understand.

Comment: But the answer you've given me is not what I know I should be getting.

Comment: If you don't know how to inverse $t(H)$ to find $H(t)$, this mean that you have to solve the equation for t. The result is : $$H(t)=2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3} V_0}\tanh\left( 2\sqrt{6\pi V_0}\:t+C\right)$$